# The definition of flat sheaves of rings on algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

Reading [Sheaves on Artin stacks](https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/qcohrevised.pdf) by M. Olsson I find this definition (3.7, (i)):

> Let $\mathcal X$ be an algebraic stack on a scheme $S$. A sheaf of rings $\mathcal A$ on $\mathcal X_{\textrm{lis-et}}$ is *flat* if for any smooth morphism $f \colon U \to V$ in $\operatorname{Lis-Et}(X)$, the natural map of sheaves on $U_{\textrm{et}}$
>   $$
> f^{-1}(\mathcal A_V) \to \mathcal A_U
> $$
>   is faithfully flat.

On the other hand, I read the book *Champs algébriques* by G. Laumon and L. Moret-Bailly, and in (12.7) there I find the following definition (I translate and adapt a little):

> A sheaf of rings $\mathcal A$ on an $S$-algebric stack $\mathcal X$ is *flat* if for any arrow $\varphi \colon U \to V$ in $\operatorname{Lis-Et}(X)$ with $\varphi$ smooth, the homomorphism of étale rings
>   $$
> \varphi^{-1}\mathcal A_V \to \mathcal A_U
> $$
>   is flat.

Now, I must be missing something, but why does the first definition require *faithful flatness* whereas the second one just *flatness*? Are those definitions actually equivalent for some reason I can't figure out?

The book by Laumon and Moret-Bailly goes on to say (Examples 12.7.1) that the structure sheaf $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}$ on an algebraic stack $\mathcal X$ is indeed flat. Does this hold if we assume the first definition of "flatness"? (I certainly hope so...)